# Cognito one User pool with multiple applications

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-cognito, amazon-cognito-triggers

I am new to aws and having trouble with cognito login.
Cognito one user pool with many other applications will use the same login function like in lambda.
google or fb able to login with the same user pool.
If the user is not right to access the application, then login process will be failed.
One user will have right to access many applications.
Anyone who can help and please advise me how can i implement this solution?
And login function call from lambda is available for social login too?

Answer (score 0):

I think that the best way to go is create a serverless lambda with all the identity workflows and there handle the multiple applications client. This can be done using the Developer credentials of Cognito. I already use this solution in many projects and have many benefits.